# How to deploy on two different glassfish domains with cargo maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, pom.xml, cargo

I'm trying to deploy my application on 2 different glassfish domains on the same server. One is called localhost-domain1, second is localhost-domain2. All my deploys go into localhost-domain1(but at least those deploy successfully).

To setup it I made 2 profiles in my POM.xml

```
<profile>
        <id>continousIntegrationA</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                            <type>remote</type>
                        </container>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>runtime</type>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.hostname>*censored*</cargo.hostname>
                                <cargo.remote.username>*censored*</cargo.remote.username>
                                <cargo.remote.password>*censored*</cargo.remote.password>
                                <cargo.remote.port>4848</cargo.remote.port>
                                <cargo.glassfish.domain.name>localhost-domain1</cargo.glassfish.domain.name>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <context>${project.name}</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.glassfish.deployment</groupId>
                            <artifactId>deployment-client</artifactId>
                            <version>3.2-b06</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>continousIntegrationB</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                            <type>remote</type>
                        </container>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>runtime</type>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.hostname>*censored*</cargo.hostname>
                                <cargo.remote.username>*censored*</cargo.remote.username>
                                <cargo.remote.password>*censored*</cargo.remote.password>
                                <cargo.remote.port>4949</cargo.remote.port>
                                <cargo.glassfish.domain.name>localhost-domain2</cargo.glassfish.domain.name>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <context>${project.name}</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.glassfish.deployment</groupId>
                            <artifactId>deployment-client</artifactId>
                            <version>3.2-b06</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Then I deploy with desired profile, yet both profiles deploy into localhost-domain1.

Comment: I've tried changing cargo version to 1.4.6. It didn't help.

Also I've seen some tutorial that named domain names as /domainX so I tried doing that. It didn't. help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with cargo.remote.port. It should actually be cargo.glassfish.admin.port. Changing name of that property fixed everything.